pyautogui not finding picture on larger screen
I have a project using pyautogui that runs perfectly on my laptop. I've made an exe of the script and tried testing it on a different computer where the 'main screen' in the settings is an external monitor. When I ran it on the other laptop it started running well but couldn't recognize one of the pictures.
Here's a code snippet demonstrating the problem:
import pyautogui as auto
import time
auto.locateOnScreen("image1.png", confidence = 0.9) #works on both computers no problem
time.sleep(1) #computer pauses for a second before continuing
auto.locateOnScreen("image2.png", confidence = 0.9) #does not work on 2nd computer, raises exception

image 1 is 30x30 and image 2 is 61x27
This entire program works well on a dell laptop, but the second locate method call didn't work on a thinkpad connected to a monitor, both run on windows 11. In my opinion, I don't think this is a result of different computers running slightly faster or slower.
Should I just lower the confidence of the locateOnScreen call or is there some other fix I can do? I can probably crop image 2 to be a little smaller if needed, but not by much.
